Corporate Dystopia book from the early 2000s
I read a book in the early 2000s (which is when I think it was published). It was set in a near future dystopia where corporations had taken over all public services. Poverty was outlawed and being poor or not consuming goods was looked down on. The protagonist was a youngish female character. She worked two jobs, one in an office and another at a video rental store. She has a breakdown and goes to her bosses house. One of the main plot points was the placement of an ad on the moon. If anyone can give me an idea about the title or author, that would be great.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a hardcover or paperback book?  Do you recall the cover art?

The bit about placing an ad on the moon made me think of "Watch this space" by Arthur C Clarke (but also of some story about 6+ by Heinlein)

Heinlein's The Man Who Sold the Moon has the ad (and Turtledove actually wrote a story called "6+")

Jennifer Government by Max Barry fits the publishing date and corporate dystopia. It also has multiple female characters but not sure about the plot points.
